# What tools are available for game script writing?

Tags: macos

I'm looking to find some software options on OS X that are geared toward writing game scripts. Features like the ability to craft dialogue trees and other non-linear script formats would be appreciated.

I own Celtx and love its ability to store character information along with various other media assets, but it's very linear and straight, film-style script based which doesn't exactly work well for game applications.

Any dedicated or more appropriate software options out there?

Comment: Possibly related, though maybe not specific to Mac: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/tools-for-game-script-storyboard

Comment: I imagine it would be hard to have a tool for this since there is nothing approaching a standard when it comes to handling game dialogue. Even the concept of a dialogue tree can take many different forms (eg. it could be a graph rather than a tree, it could be keyword based or phrase based, or both, etc)

Comment: @Kylotan: Actually, it wouldn't be too hard to come up with a reasonably extensible and generalizable dialog system. After all, a tree is just a graph with certain limitations (and most dialog trees aren't fully trees, as they allow for non-tree branching). The problem is the tool support, doubly so with the possibility of localization and the ability to attach other data (speech files, etc) to dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that might work is [Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/) for [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/). Here’s an [excited rant](http://beastwithin.org/users/wwwwolf/fantasy/avarthrel/blog/2011/05/lets-just-use-emacs.html) about how Emacs with `visual-line-mode` and `org-mode` is awesome for scriptwriting. As for nonlinear scripts, Org-Mode lets you make [internal links](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html) wherever you want.

**Warning:** Emacs is designed for power users, and it takes time to become effective with it.